# Dagre-D3 or D3 not working on different server

Tags: d3.js, svg, server, dagre-d3

Hy, so unfortunately i cant post my hole source code, neither can i link to it.

But because of this, I'm ok if i don't get a concrete answer, just some guidance.

So my situation is this:

I have made, with the help of dagre-d3.js and d3.js a hierarchy organizational chart. It works perfectly on local (WAMP) environment, but when i try it on the live server, which runs linux (ubuntu), not all the functions are working correctly.

But what i don't understand is that the functions that are not working 100% percent are just front-end svg stuff, so there is no back-end connection when i try these operations.

Locally i tested it with windows 7, 8 on wamp and in chrome, firefox, even internet explorer, and every functionality works, when i load it from the server, some functionalities are not working. And the fact is that i don't get any error messages, so its not like d3.js or dagre-d3.js isnt correctly loadded, because it is, the graph is rendered correctly.

So to finish up, my question is this, can there be some server side configuration which interferes with the rendered SVG graph? And if no, then where should i start looking? How to even check wheres the problem?

Thank you in advance for any kind of guidance.

Comment: Possibly some sort of race condition. If something wasn't getting loaded, I'd expect to see errors on the console. You're probably going to have to recreate an example of the problem that you can share to get an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so at last i figured it out.

On the live server there was a different version of php which, when using **json_encode** converted the ids to strings, and because of this the dagre-d3 plugin didn't work as it should have, some functionalities did, but not all.